# Rails 2.3.16 associations giving ArgumentError when using associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I'm upgrading a legacy project from Rails 2.3.2 to 2.3.16 (as a result of the recently-publicised vulnerability), but when I try and access the `has_many` association on any of the models, I get an `ArgumentError` from `sanitize_sql`.

```
class User
  has_many :games, :dependent => destroy
end

class Game
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I try and call `Game.last.user` it returns the correct `User` object, but calling `User.last.games` I get the following error stack:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
  from /home/username/application/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.16/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:174:in `sanitize_sql'
  from /home/username/application/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.16/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:174:in `send'
  from /home/username/application/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.16/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:174:in `sanitize_sql'
  from /home/username/application/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.16/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:41:in `find'
  from /home/username/application/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.16/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:423:in `find_target'
  from /home/username/application/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.16/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:365:in `load_target'
  from /home/username/application/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.16/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:140:in `inspect'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:310:in `output_value'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:159:in `eval_input'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `catch'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
  from /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/irb:17
```

I'm running Rails 2.3.16 on Ruby 1.8.7; if there are any other details that I've left out that might be helpful in diagnosing the issue, then let me know.

**EDIT**

I seem to have temporarily worked around this issue by editing the error-causing line in the `activerecord-2.3.16/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb` file like so:

```
# Forwards the call to the reflection class.
def sanitize_sql(sql, table_name = @reflection.klass.quoted_table_name)
  @reflection.klass.send(:sanitize_sql, sql) #, table_name)
end
```

I would, obviously, prefer a more long-term solution as I'm not 100% certain that this isn't going to have additional knock-on problems down the line.

Comment: what is the patch level of you ree version? do you still get the same error using ree1.8.7-2012.02? I had some problems with ree-1.8.7-2011.12

Comment: I was using ruby-1.8.7-p371, but I'll give ree a shot and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope, changing to ree-1.8.7-2012.02 doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem and can't find what's causing it.

I also came to the conclusion of editing this line. I made a monkey patch initializer:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class AssociationProxy #:nodoc:
      def sanitize_sql(sql, table_name = @reflection.klass.quoted_table_name)
        @reflection.klass.send(:sanitize_sql, sql)#, table_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I hope I can find the real cause soon though, because this shouldn't be necessary. Any more progress on your issue?